# Rewriting inside quantified propositions in Coq?

Tags: coq, tactic, rewriting

Is there a simple way to use rewrites inside quantified Props? As an example, consider the following:

```
Goal forall (xs : list nat) (ys : list nat),
  (forall x, In x (xs ++ ys) -> x < 10) -> True.
Proof.
  intros.
```

makes the context look like

```
A: Type
xs, ys: list nat
H: forall x : nat, In x (xs ++ ys) -> x < 10
```

Now, recall that

```
in_app_iff
     : forall (A : Type) (l l' : list A) (a : A),
       In a (l ++ l') <-> In a l \/ In a l'
```

However, `rewrite in_app_iff in H.` gives me an error:

```
Found no subterm matching "In ?y (?l ++ ?l0)" in the current goal.
```

I want it to transform the context into

```
H: forall x : nat, (In x xs \/ In x ys) -> x < 10
```

I am aware that I can do this by first specializing `x` inside an assert environment or something, but it would be really nifty if I didn't have to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the tactic `setoid_rewrite` lets you rewrite under binders.
Here is [the reference manual link](https://coq.github.io/doc/master/refman/addendum/generalized-rewriting.html?highlight=setoid_rewrite#coq:tacn.setoid_rewrite).

For your example this gives:

```ml
From Coq Require Import List.
Goal forall (xs : list nat) (ys : list nat),
  (forall x, In x (xs ++ ys) -> x < 10) -> True.
Proof.
  intros xs ys H.
```

The context is

```ml
xs, ys : list nat
H : forall x : nat, In x (xs ++ ys) -> x < 10
========================= (1 / 1)
True
```

then writing

```ml
  setoid_rewrite in_app_iff in H.
```

gives you

```ml
xs, ys : list nat
H : forall x : nat, In x xs \/ In x ys -> x < 10
========================= (1 / 1)
True
```